# Minimal example of HTTP server doing asynchronous database queries?

Tags: asynchronous, elixir

I'm playing with different asynchronous HTTP servers to see how they can handle multiple simultaneous connections. To force a time-consuming I/O operation I use the `pg_sleep` PostgreSQL function to emulate a time-consuming database query. Here is for instance what I did with Node.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://al:al@localhost/al";
/* SQL query that takes a long time to complete */
var slowQuery = 'SELECT 42 as number, pg_sleep(0.300);';

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query(slowQuery, [], function(err, result) {
      done();
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end("Result: " + result.rows[0].number);
    });
  });
})

console.log("Serve http://127.0.0.1:3001/")
server.listen(3001)
```

So this a very simple request handler that does an SQL query taking 300ms and returns a response. When I try benchmarking it I get the following results:

```
$ ab -n 20 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:3001/
Time taken for tests:   0.678 seconds
Complete requests:      20
Requests per second:    29.49 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       339.116 [ms] (mean)
```

This shows clearly that requests are executed in parallel. Each request takes 300ms to complete and because we have 2 batches of 10 requests executed in parallel, it takes 600ms overall.

Now I'm trying to do the same with Elixir, since I heard it does asynchronous I/O transparently. Here is my naive approach:

```
defmodule Toto do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options) do
    {:ok, pid} = Postgrex.Connection.start_link(
      username: "al", password: "al", database: "al")
    options ++ [pid: pid]
  end

  def call(conn, opts) do
    sql = "SELECT 42, pg_sleep(0.300);"
    result = Postgrex.Connection.query!(opts[:pid], sql, [])
    [{value, _}] = result.rows
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
    |> send_resp(200, "Result: #{value}")
  end
end
```

In case that might relevant, here is my supervisor:

```
defmodule Toto.Supervisor do
  use Application

  def start(type, args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(Plug.Adapters.Cowboy, [Toto, []], function: :http),
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Toto.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

As you might expect, this doesn't give me the expected result:

```
$ ab -n 20 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Time taken for tests:   6.056 seconds
Requests per second:    3.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3028.038 [ms] (mean)
```

It looks like there's no parallelism, requests are handled one after the other. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elixir should be completely fine with this setup. The difference is that your node.js code is creating a connection to the database for every request. However, in your Elixir code, init is called once (and not per request!) so you end-up with a single process that sends queries to Postgres for all requests, which then becomes your bottleneck.

The easiest solution would be to move the connection to Postgres out of `init` and into `call`. However, I would advise you to [use Ecto](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto) which will set up a connection pool to the database too. You can also play with the [pool configuration](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex#L44-L46) for optimal results.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE** This was just test code, if you want to do something like this see @AlexMarandon's Ecto pool answer instead.

I've just been playing with moving the connection setup as José suggested:

```
defmodule Toto do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options) do
    options
  end

  def call(conn, opts) do
    { :ok, pid } = Postgrex.Connection.start_link(username: "chris", password: "", database: "ecto_test")
    sql = "SELECT 42, pg_sleep(0.300);"
    result = Postgrex.Connection.query!(pid, sql, [])
    [{value, _}] = result.rows
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
    |> send_resp(200, "Result: #{value}")
  end
end
```

With results:

```
% ab -n 20 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Time taken for tests:   0.832 seconds
Requests per second:    24.05 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       415.818 [ms] (mean)
```

Comment: Cool! Remember that a connection pool would be far the best way to go as establishing a connection to the database is not cheap. You would have better results too!

Comment: Actually this code creates connections but never closes it, so it stops working after a while :)

Comment: @AlexMarandon - yeah, you should really use Ecto pools as José says so I will upvote your answer. This was just for demo purposes but good call pointing it out in case someone coming along later doesn't realise that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I came up with following [José's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29460248/348867):

```
defmodule Toto do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options) do
    options
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    sql = "SELECT 42, pg_sleep(0.300);"
    result = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(Repo, sql, [])
    [{value, _}] = result.rows
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
    |> send_resp(200, "Result: #{value}")
  end
end
```

For this to work we need to declare a repo module:

```
defmodule Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :toto
end
```

And start that repo in the supervisor:

```
defmodule Toto.Supervisor do
  use Application

  def start(type, args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(Plug.Adapters.Cowboy, [Toto, []], function: :http),
      worker(Repo, [])
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Toto.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

As José mentioned, I got the best performance by tweaking the configuration a bit:

```
config :toto, Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "al",
  username: "al",
  password: "al",
  size: 10,
  lazy: false
```

Here is the result of my benchmark (after a few runs so that the pool has the time to "warm up") with default configuration:

```
$ ab -n 20 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Time taken for tests:   0.874 seconds
Requests per second:    22.89 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       436.890 [ms] (mean)
```

And here is the result with `size: 10` and `lazy: false`:

```
$ ab -n 20 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Time taken for tests:   0.619 seconds
Requests per second:    32.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       309.564 [ms] (mean)
```